# Run cmd as administrator using java under Windows

Tags: java, cmd

Using java, I run cmd to be able to execute a ttl file.

My code:

```
    try {
        String[] command = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "cd C:\software\teraterm", "& TTPMacro C:\file\execute.ttl param1 param2 param3"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

But I want cmd to be run as admin
so I added **runas /savecred /user:.\Administrator** in my code,
but it is not working anymore:

```
    try {
        String[] command = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "runas /savecred /user:.\\Administrator", "cd C:\software\teraterm", "& TTPMacro C:\file\execute.ttl param1 param2 param3"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

What is wrong with this?

I've updated code to check input stream, but there is no output

```
    try {
        String[] command = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "runas /savecred /user:.\\Administrator", "cd C:\software\teraterm", "& TTPMacro C:\file\execute.ttl param1 param2 param3"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String l;
        while((l=br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.print(l);
        }

        p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: do you get an error message? I assume you'll have to provide login and password for an admin

Comment: It's always good practice to collect the standard out and standard error streams from a process started by `Runtime.exec()`. But it's particularly important where something isn't working, because those streams will probably be the only source of diagnostic information.

Comment: the cmd window did not show up and there is no exception...

Comment: I've added the following code to check the inputstream but there is no output

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String l;
        while((l=br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.print(l);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Meta: although not stated, this Q and A is only for Windows and is useless on other systems

`runas` can only run a *program* (with arguments); `cd` is a builtin function of `cmd` not a program. Also `cmdone & cmdtwo` is a feature of `cmd`, not something `runas` can do. You need to put your commands into a `cmd /c` invocation, much as you did for running directly from Java `Runtime.exec` (which also can only run a single program), except that `runas` requires its program-to-run to be exactly one argument, not optionally several that are (re)joined. So:

```
String[] command = new String[]{"runas","/user:administrator","/savecred", // these must be separated args
        "cmd /c cd directory & executable data"}; // these must be all one argument
```

Also in Java String literals, backslash is used as an escape character, so you must double each one (in pathnames or otherwise).

Finally if `runas` doesn't have already-saved credentials it prompts for the password. This prompt is not a line, so you can't read it with `BufferedReader.readLine()`. You can read it as bytes (into an array) with the input stream, or chars (ditto) with the `InputStreamReader`. However, as something of a hack, since `runas` doesn't pass its own stdhandles to its child but instead a new console window, you can just ignore the prompt and *always* write the password to `p.getOutputStream()` whether it's needed or not, and if it's not it will be discarded.

Comment: thanks for the info..

`String cmd = "cmd.exe /c cd C:\\software\\teraterm & TTPMacro C:\\file\\execute.ttl param1 param2 param3"
String[] command = new String[]{"runas","/user:administrator","/savecred", cmd};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream);
osw.write("password");
osw.write("\r\n");
osw.flush();`

it is still not working. could you tell me what's wrong with my code?
if I just executed cmd (non admin), it is working
`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

Comment: Does it create the new window or not? If so, look in the window. Try `cmd /k` instead of `cmd /c` to make the window persist if necessary. If not, try reading from `p.getErrorStream()` -- as bytes not line(s) just in case -- and display it; if that doesn't help try `p.getInputStream()`.